# Why Database is not used with 3D and Drawing softwares (to store points and other primitive shapes)?

Tags: database, architecture, 3d, software-design, 3d-modelling

My question is why Databases are not used with Drawing, 3D Modelling, 3D Design, Game Engines and architecture etc. software to save the current state of the images or the stuff that is present on the screen or is the part of a project in a Database.

One obvious answer is the speed, the speed of retrieving or saving all the millions of triangles or points forming the geometry is very low, as there would be hundreds or thousands of queries per second, but is it really the cause? Considering the apparent advantages of using databases  can allow sharing the design live over a network when it is being saved at a common location, and more than one people can work on it at a time or can use can give live feedback when something is being designed when it is being shared, specially when time based update is used, such as update after every 5 or 10 seconds, which is not as good as live synchronization, but should be quick enough. What is the basic problem in the use of Databases in this type of software that caused them not to be used this way, or new algorithms or techniques not being developed or studied for optimizing the benefits of using them this way? And why this idea wasn't researched a lot.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "database"? what do you suppose a "database"'s advantages are? how would you distinguish what a "database" does from whatever it is you think cad/3d software does? I can't help but think that this question suffers from a very fuzzy assumption of what a database is.

Comment: By database, here i mean using one of the DBMS (commercial) to maintain and store the points and related info of the 3d space.

Comment: but why do you want to use a DBMS for that? Please pay attention to my other questions.

Comment: My supposed advantage was the in-built capability to maintain and return information using a query instead of managing the storage mechanism that is specially developed for the application which would allow several designers to share that workspace/3d world or whatever one would call it, and work simultaneously over computers connected over a network, but you have answered my question, and that sharing workspace can be done by other means and doesn't essentially require a database, and decreased speed and difficulty to program are the reason DB is not used in this area. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is essentially speed. The speed of writing information to a disk drive is an order of magnitude slower than writing it to ram. The speed of network access is in turn an order of magnitude slower than writing or reading a hard disk. Live sharing apps like the one you describe are indeed possible though, but wouldn't necessarily require what you would call a "database", nor would using a database be such a great idea. The reason more don't exist is that they are actually fiendishly difficult to program. Programming by itself is difficult enough, even just thinking in a straight line, with a single narrative. But to program something like that requires you to be able to accurately visualise multiple parallel dimensions acting on the same data simultaneously, without breaking anything. This is actually difficult.

Comment: It's not an order of magnitude difference between RAM and HD, it's three orders of magnitude -- and that's when you're using an SSD.  For rotational storage, the difference is five orders of magnitude.  See [latency numbers every programmer should know](https://gist.github.com/2841832).

Comment: Thank you @DietrichEpp that's helpful to know, even though I wrote this answer so long ago I don't remember writing it!

Answer (score 1):

Your obvious answer is correct; I'm not an expert in that particular field but I'm at a point that even from a distance you can see that's (probably) the main reason.

This doesn't negate the possibility that such systems will use a database at some point.

> Considering the apparent advantages of using databases can allow
>   sharing the design live over a network when it is being saved at a
>   common location...

True, but just because the information is being passed around doesn't mean that you have to store it in a database in order to be able to do that.  Once something is in memory you can do anything with it - the issue with not persisting stuff is that you will lose data if the server fails / stops / etc.

I'll be interested to see if anyone has a more enlightened answer.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting discussion... I have a biased view towards avoiding adding too much "structure" (as in in the indexes, tables, etc. in a DBMS solution) to spacial problems or challenges beyond those that cannot be readily recreated from a much smaller subset of data.  I think if the original poster would look at the problem from what is truly needed to answer the need/develop solutions ... he may not need to query a DBMS nearly as often... so the DBMS in question might relate to a 3D space but in fact be a small subset of total values in that space... in a similar way that digital displays do not concern themselves with every chnage in pixel (or voxel) value but only those that have changed.  Since most 3D problems would have a much lower "refresh" rate vs video displays the hits on the DBMS would be infrequent enough to possibly make a 3D DB look "live".

Comment: Is this an answer or should it be a comment?